# Air Native Extensions for Android In-App Billing

Tags: android, air, manifest, native, billing

I'm trying to set up native extensions to work with in-app billing through an air app.

I'm able to send purchase requests to the market but I'm not able to get a response back.

I've tracked it down to the AndroidManifest.xml file that gets created. In order to do it in Java you need to reference specific classes, but when I do it through Flash I don't know how to reference those Java classes.

As far as I know Native extensions only allow you to call methods from Java. Is there any way I would be able to reference those specific Java classes through Flash in the manifest file?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to ship in-app billing? I am facing lot of issues with build. Can you share your build script?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question fully, but here are some elements of answer:

-Native extensiosn have an issue with java libraries, it might also be a problem with aidl files : [AIR 3 Native Extensions for Android - Can I/How to include 3rd party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732742/air-3-native-extensions-for-android-can-i-how-to-include-3rd-party-libraries)

-About the manifest additions, you can modify the manifest of the final apk this way : 
Go to NAMEOFYOURAPP-app.xml

After :

```
<!--The suppression of android.permission.INTERNET will prevent you from debugging.-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

You can add permissions

After :

```
<![CDATA[
    <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
```

You can add activities and services.

In your case, instead of :

```
            <application android:enabled="true">
                <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
```

Write :

```
                <application android:enabled="true">
                    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>

<service android:name="BillingService" />

<receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

                </application>
```

But for your applicaiton to work, you still have to fix some .jar problems (as states above)

Comment: How would I add a service that is declared in the native Java code? Specifically, the BillingService and BillingReceiver

Answer (score 0):

You can have reference to the classes in manifest as you do for native java. please refer [Can Manifest Receiver for In app payment be moved to Java code instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547507) if you come across any issue