# Getting Error : Could not find method com.urbanairship.Autopilot.automaticTakeOff

Tags: android, apache-flex, urbanairship.com, ane

I wanted to create an ane file using UrbanAirship latest sdk. I have added Autopilot metadata`(<meta-data android:name="com.urbanairship.autopilot" android:value="com.sample.aneAndroid.TakeOffHelper" /> )` in my app-xml under the application block and also created a subclass of Autopilot and added AirshipConfigOptions there. When I try to call `Autopilot.automaticTakeOff(app);` in the class which implement FREFunction it gives below error-

```
02-03 17:14:11.949  23088-23088/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.urbanairship.Autopilot.automaticTakeOff, referenced from method com.sample.aneAndroid.UAPushNotificationExtensionSubscribeFunction.call
02-03 17:14:11.949  23088-23088/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 3322: Lcom/urbanairship/Autopilot;.automaticTakeOff (Landroid/app/Application;)V
```

TakeOffHelper.java

```
@Override
    public AirshipConfigOptions createAirshipConfigOptions(Context context) {
        Log.v("Autopilot", "createAirshipConfigOptions called");
        AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(context.getApplicationContext());
        Log.v("Autopilot", "createAirshipConfigOptions called " + options);
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
        Log.v("Autopilot", "onAirshipReady called");
         DefaultNotificationFactory defaultNotificationFactory = new DefaultNotificationFactory(UAirship.getApplicationContext());
        defaultNotificationFactory.setColor(NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT);

        // Set it
        airship.getPushManager().setNotificationFactory(defaultNotificationFactory);

        // Enable Push
        airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true);

    }
```

UAPushNotificationExtensionInitFunction.java

```
public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

        UAPushNotificationExtensionContext nec = (UAPushNotificationExtensionContext) context;
        android.app.Activity activity = nec.getActivity();
        nec.activity = activity;

         Application app = context.getActivity().getApplication();
         Autopilot.automaticTakeOff(app);}
```

Comment: How are you building your ANE?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to an incorrect .jar file.  I use a command in the following format to build my ANEs:

`adt -package -target ane bin/airshipWrapper.ane src/extension.xml -swc lib/airshipWrapper.swc -platform Android-ARM -C working/android . -platform default -C working/default .`

`bin/airshipWrapper.ane` is your target location for the ANE

`src/extension.xml` is the path to your extension.xml for the ANE you're trying to build

`lib/airshipWrapper.swc` is the path to the swc with your Actionscript classes for the ANE (this is where you put your class that calls `ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext()`).

`working/android` is your path containing your `airshipWrapper.jar` and `library.swf`

`airshipWrapper.jar` is a combined jar file with your Java classes and all library classes needed*

`library.swf` is extracted from your `airshipWrapper.swc`.

`working/default` is your path containing a `library.swf` with the same signature as your classes in `airshipWrapper.swc` (so your project doesn't break when you run it in the emulator)

*For the jar file, I export it from my Java project, then run a jar update with any necessary library classes.  I use `ant`, but any method of extracting classes from one jar and updating another will do.

See also [AIR 3 Native Extensions for Android - Can I/How to include 3rd party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732742/air-3-native-extensions-for-android-can-i-how-to-include-3rd-party-libraries) for more reading about the combined .jar file.

Comment: I am doing the same thing and it work fine when I was using previous version of urbanairship library(4.0.2).I am getting this error when I try to use new urbanairship sdk(6.4.1) in ane.

Comment: Do you see com.urbanairship.Autopilot in your ANE?

Comment: Yes, When I unzip final jar file urban airship files are available in it.